# code segment referenced again with second plugin crashes

Tags: linux, gcc, dynamic, linker, dlopen

I'd like to understand the dynamic-linker/loader behaviour on Linux box in the problematic case I work upon.

Our code that crashes is loaded as a plugin (dlopen(libwrapper.so, RTLD_GLOBAL)). libwrapper.so is just a thin layer that loads another plugins that do the real job.  These plugins can be named: P1 and P2, each of these depend on common library called F (all together very much simplified).

Wrapper (libwrapper.so) is introduced to allow loading Pn without RTLD_GLOBAL, since that flag set leads to obvious linkage problems loading Pns (they have the same API). RTLD_DEEPBIND is not an option since target platform is too old - does not support it.

To our surprise, the problem manifests in F library at the load time of P2 (when P1 is already loaded (and initialized) and F as its implicit dependency). At the time P2 is explicitly loaded (dlopen(libP2.so, RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_NOW)), dynamic linker reports no problems, but calling code within F to instantiate some type instances defined in F (again) leads to segmentation faults on various places (in case one is skipped / out-commented, it crashes on another place - therefore didn't spent time to investigate the code pattern that might be troublesome, since more general problem / misunderstanding is suspected). There are no inlined functions used, code is linked with -Wl,-E, visibility default, GCC is 3.4.4.. F code is very much stable and used within standalone apps or as part of plugins in the past.

I thought to link F as static library to workaround any problem there might be with the dynamic linker, but result is the same.

My view on the topic:

- linking F as dynamic library leads dynamic linker to "know" F is referenced second time loading P2 and just increments the reference counter and does not call static initializers (which is ok), but does relocations (again, and this seems to be problematic).
- linking F as static library leads dynamic linker to load F code as statically linked part of P2 (P2F) and does relocations within P2F. However, "somehow" common symbols from F gets messed up with P1F code instance.

Assumption about the workaround to make the code at least work:

- link P1 ... Pn in a single shared library (single plugin), whether F is shared / static doesn't matter. This way any relocation is done only once.

I'd appreciate any feedback is my view on the topic wrong / too simplified / missing important part? Is this some known GCC / binutils bug from the past?

Answer (score 1):

> My view on the topic:

Your view on the topic is wrong; but there is no way to prove that to you.

Write a minimal test case that simulates what your system does, and still crashes in a similar way. Update your question with actual broken code; then we can tell you *exactly* what the problem is.

There is also a very good chance that in reducing the problem to the minimal example, you'll discover what the problem is yourself.

Either way you'll understand the problem, and will learn something new.

Comment: Is there any specific part in the text above that can be claimed "it is wrong"? It would help me to focus more efficiently.

Comment: @user2208924 Yes: this part: "linking F as dynamic library leads dynamic linker to "know" F is referenced second time loading P2 and just increments the reference counter and does not call static initializers" -- correct up to that point, but the next assertion: "but does relocations" is false.